# How to generate CGPath values from logo

Tags: objective-c, cgpath

At the bottom of [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20190224021349/http://ronnqvi.st:80/controlling-animation-timing) page there's an interesting animation. It's basically animating a `CAShapeLayer` with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

[image: animation]
<sub>(source: [ronnqvi.st](http://ronnqvi.st/images/peak.gif))</sub>

I wanted to see how this was accomplished so I went to the [github](https://github.com/d-ronnqvist/blogpost-codesample-PullToRefresh) page and found [this](https://github.com/d-ronnqvist/blogpost-codesample-PullToRefresh/blob/master/PullToRefreshAnimation/PullToRefreshAnimation/SampleViewController.m#L308). Below is a small piece of the code.

```
- (CGPathRef)loadPath
{
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    // load
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path,     NULL, 7.50878897, 25.2871097);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, 7.50878897, 25.2871097,  21.7333976, 26.7812495, 29.6894527, 20.225586);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, 37.6455074, 13.6699219,  39.367189,  3.85742195, 31.9697262, 1.25976564);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, 24.5722639, -1.33789083, 21.99707,   10.9072268, 21.99707,   22.2255862);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, 21.9970685, 33.5439456,  15.9355469, 45.8212894, 8.99707031, 47.7294922);
    ...
```

How can I generate these `CGPath` values? Any kind of example would be helpful.

Comment: I don't know if there is any easier ways but what comes to my mind is to draw the logo , and take it's `CGPath`.
I mean to make a little app to draw it by finger touch, and log it's path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a simple SVG and use https://github.com/arielelkin/PocketSVG

Answer (score 0):

I did buy this one: http://www.beziercode.com/  It's working nicely.